# UINavigationController Pushing Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get this graphing calculator to work. I have two view controllers, one for the calculator and one for the graph. separately they work fine. But when I push the graph view controller on the stack for some reason it doesn't work.

This is the part of the code that computes a y-value to draw on the display for the graph

```
+ (double)evaluateExpression:(id)anExpression
         usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryOfVariables
{
    CalculatorBrain *brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    double result = 0;

    for (id anObject in anExpression) {
        if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
             brain.operand = [anObject doubleValue];
        } else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            if ([anObject characterAtIndex:0] == '%') {
                 brain.operand = [[dictionaryOfVariables objectForKey:anObject] doubleValue];
            } else {
                 result = [brain performOperation:anObject];
            }
        }
     }

    [brain release];
    return result;      
}
```

for some reason, this function works fine the first five times it is called, but on the sixth time, the debugger says that `anObject` has been deallocated and my program crashes (confirmed with NSZombiesEnabled). `anExpression` is an NSArray with either NSNumbers or NSStrings in it. I cannot fathom how or why stuff in this array is being deallocated.

this is the code that pushes the `GraphViewController` onto the UINavigationController stack, and gives it it's properties:

```
- (IBAction)graph:(UIButton *)sender
{
    GraphViewController *gvc = [[GraphViewController alloc] init];
    gvc.graphModel.expression = [self brain].expression;
    gvc.graphModel.scale = 30;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gvc animated:YES];
    [gvc release];
}
```

`gvc.graphModel.expression` is the expression that gets passed into `evaluateExpression: usingVariableValues:` above.

and this is the code called for [self brain].expression

```
- (id)expression
{
    id anExpression = [internalExpression copy];
    [anExpression autorelease];
    return anExpression;
}
```

This is the code that puts objects into `anExpression` in the first place:

```
- (void)addTerm:(id)anObject
{
    if (!internalExpression) internalExpression = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [internalExpression addObject:anObject];
}
```

Note: `anExpression`, `internalExpression`, and `expression` all mean pretty much the same thing. they hold the expression I'm trying to graph.

I know this is a bit complex, but I was hoping someone could at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is `anObject` released anywhere within `performOperation:`?

Comment: I didn't think so, but to test your idea I gave `performOperation:` a copy of `anObject` instead of `anObject` directly, and now it works! But I still don't see where `performOperation:` is realeasing `anObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely something is releasing one of the objects in your array when it doesn't actually own the object.

Comment: I don't see it. Is there a way to find out who's releasing it using the debugger?

Comment: Not that I know of. But using the "Build and Analyze" option in XCode has a good chance of flagging it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I think its because you are auto-releasing the the `anExpression` object and the calling object is not retaining it so when the auto-release pool is eventually drained `anExpression` is ebing be released. This would also explain why it sometimes works.

I think using the below should solve this:

```
gvc.graphModel.expression = [[self brain].expression retain];
```

Comment: I tried that, no luck (expression is a retain @property in graphModel). It's not the array (expression) that's being deallocated, it's the objects in the array that are being deallocated. when I send a message to one of the objects in the array, the program crashes.

Comment: this is the error message I get in the debugger console:
`GraphingCalculator[39904:207] *** -[CFString isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b306b0`.

0x4b306b0 is `anObject` in the for-in loop in the evaluateExpression: usingVariableValues: method.